# Importing Excel data using SSIS using unique ID's

Tags: sql, visual-studio-2010, ssis

I have one excel file that I want to import into two different tables, tblUni and tblUser.

I have a third table which contains the id's from the other two tables:

```
tblUni_Students
Id
UniId
StudentId
```

What I need is when I import the excel data into the first two tables, for each record, the newly created ids to be inserted into the Uni_Students table also.

Using SSIS, I have managed to import the data into two sql destinations but cannot seem to then take the new ids from these destinations to then insert into the lookup table.

[image]

Can anyone advise please. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

It's a bit difficult to answer without knowing the target database or the structure of the data but speaking generally this would be much better done by adding the data into a "load" table. i.e. one who's sole reason is to temporarily hold data while you process it, you would then update the tblStudent, tblUni and tblUni_Student tables from the load area using SQL statements either via Procedure or via an `Execute SQL Task` component.

Answer (score 0):

You'd it as an oledbcommand component, where the command is to insert values into the table. Then in the same component you'd output the generated identity. Assign the generated identity to a new column in the output, and now you have all your data plus the generated identity in the dataflow.

This will be processed one row at a time, so it will be slow. Personally I'd put it in a staging table and do it as Ciarán described.